# JPA CreateEntityManagerFactory() method hangs

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using this method in the following way

```
EntityManagerFactory emftemp = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("XYZ");
```

and my `persistence.xml` has the following entry for this unit

```
<persistence-unit name="XYZ" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions" value="true=1, false=0"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@aesop-db.corp.nlg1.com:1521:TLCSDEV4"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="abcd"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="abcd"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.timeout" value="120"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="2"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="2"/>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="60"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

This is a Java application and I am using the hibernate3.jar and I am using ejb3-persistence.jar and JDK1.5.

The problem is that everytime I run the application, it hangs on this call . Its not throwing any exception or error . It just hangs at that point.

Can anyone help in identifying why it does not move forward ?

Comment: This just happened to me. Turns out it was creating an index, which took a loooooong time. I found this out by using the MySQL Workbench to inspect active connections and their running queries.

Comment: @TYS : I'am facing the same issue.Please help me if you had got the solution.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

1. When something hangs it's often IO/networking issues to blame. So, try to make sure that the DB is really alive, and that you can connect to it from your computer.
2. This could be a duplicate of [Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory takes ages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966281/persistence-createentitymanagerfactory-takes-ages)

Comment: I am able to connect to the database from Toad. Toad is the db client on my machine. I can connect to it using the same db url and username,password and I am able to make queries/updates etc to it.Secondly it only hangs. Even if I leave it for half an hr it just wont move forward from that point. Any leads on where I could sniff around looking for the problem ?

Comment: you could try to use some malformed DB URL to see if it throws any errors, if it doesn't it would mean that it's not network related... and are you using the latest hibernate?

Comment: I have tried using a malformed url, it still hangs in the same place. I am currently using the hibernate3.jar . Dont know if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: you could try to get the latest http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.6.9.Final/ and see if it helps...

Comment: @oleg thanks for all your responses, I downloaded and tried with the new hibernate jar as well, but no luck yet ! I ran into some issues with the hibernate-annotations.jar. So I removed that because the latest version of hibernate.jar has the annotations bundled in it . but tht's about it. I am still hitting the wall !

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts on this problem, I got busy with something else, so wasn't pursuing it, but I really have to get it to work !

Comment: You should enable [Hibernate logging](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) and post the log here to make it easier to analyze the problem...

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue against an Oracle 11g database with only three entities defined but a very large DB.  After commenting out the following line from persistence.xml, the issue was resolved.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```